# baselinestretch not functioning with \tikz inline (and generally \tikz inline not taking line spacing)

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-styles, line-spacing, inline

When using `\tikz` inline, mwe below say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

He moonlight difficult engrossed an it sportsmen. Interested has all devonshire difficulty gay assistance joy. Unaffected at ye of compliment alteration to. Place voice no arise along to. Parlors waiting so against me no. Wishing calling are warrant settled was luckily. Express besides it present if at an opinion visitor. Questions explained agreeable preferred strangers too him her son. Set put shyness offices his females him distant. Improve has message besides shy himself cheered however how son. Quick judge other leave ask first chief her. Indeed or remark \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{ \draw [|-|] (0,-1) rectangle (3,2); } silent seemed narrow be. Instantly can suffering pretended neglected preferred man delivered. Perhaps fertile brandon do imagine to cordial cottage. On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.

\end{document}
```

We see that:

[image]

We see that the Tikz picture runs flush to the lines above and below.

Is it possible to do anything to have the tikz picture behave as if it was indeed a true inline character and take the spacing above and below it equal to the inter-line separation.

I have a generalised command based on \tikz that I am using this for and hence using \vspace above and below won't work, since if inserted in the first line, there will be an extra padding at the top that is unwanted (noting that the line separation won't add padding at the top, e.g. in a list, for the first line).

Comment: this is unrelated to tikz you would see the same with a large character or inline math

Comment: You are right, but this issue is very often encountered when using tikz and there is no solution that I can find, so I want to see this resolved to help myself and others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this is not really a problem with TikZ but with anything that produces something that is taller than a normal line.

Nonetheless, here are some ideas to approach this a bit automatically.

Firstly, there are the keys `above space` and `below space` that should be used as the option to the `tikzpicture` environment or the `\tikz` macro (or as part of the `every picture` style. They add the given length to the top or the bottom of the picture. They both can used with the same distance with `above and below space`.

Secondly, there's `pad above and below` which basically does the same but only if the picture is taller than `\baselineskip`. I've given it the default value of `.25*\baselineskip` to add above and below. Feel free to change this or use an explicit value.

Once could actually differentiate between pictures that are too tall (too much height) and/or those that are to deep (too much depth) and treat them differently.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  above space/.style={execute at end picture={\path[reset cm]([yshift={#1}]current bounding box.north);}},
  below space/.style={execute at end picture={\path[reset cm]([yshift={-(#1)}]current bounding box.south);}},
  above and below space/.style={above space={#1}, below space={#1}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pad above and below/.default=.25*\baselineskip, % maybe factor .5?
  pad above and below/.style={
    execute at end picture={%
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south}}
                                {\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north}}}%
      \ifdim\pgf@y>\baselineskip\relax
        \begingroup % PGF of % \path[reset cm]([yshift={#1}]current bounding box.north);
          \pgftransformreset % \path[reset cm]([yshift={-(#1)}]current bounding box.south);
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{#1}}{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{north}}}%
          \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{-(#1)}}{\pgfpointanchor{current bounding box}{south}}}%
          \pgfusepath{discard}%
        \endgroup
      \fi}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

He moonlight difficult engrossed an it sportsmen. Interested has all devonshire difficulty gay assistance joy. Unaffected at ye of compliment alteration to. Place voice no arise along to. Parlors waiting so against me no. Wishing calling are warrant settled was luckily. Express besides it present if at an opinion visitor. Questions explained agreeable preferred strangers too him her son. Set put shyness offices his females him distant. Improve has message besides shy himself cheered however how son. Quick judge other leave ask first chief her. Indeed or remark
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex, pad above and below]\draw [|-|] (0,-1) rectangle (3,2);
silent seemed narrow be. Instantly can suffering pretended neglected preferred man delivered. Perhaps fertile brandon do imagine to cordial cottage. On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, than you after the following

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

He moonlight difficult engrossed an it sportsmen. Interested has all devonshire difficulty gay assistance joy. Unaffected at ye of compliment alteration to. Place voice no arise along to. Parlors waiting so against me no. Wishing calling are warrant settled was luckily. Express besides it present if at an opinion visitor. Questions explained agreeable preferred strangers too him her son. Set put shyness offices his females him distant. Improve has message besides shy himself cheered however how son. Quick judge other leave ask first chief her. Indeed or remark 
    \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\draw (0,-1) rectangle (3,2); 
                           \path (0,-1.16) -- (0,2.16);} % <--- add vertical space
silent seemed narrow be. Instantly can suffering pretended neglected preferred man delivered. Perhaps fertile brandon do imagine to cordial cottage. On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite.

\end{document}
```